# 7 down: The end of the flower festival (6)

Tags: cryptic-crosswords

Can anybody help me to understand this cryptic crossword clue? I have the following letters:

> E_S_E_

I know the answer:

> EASTER

But I can't make sense of the clue.

Comment: Do you have any crossing letters?

Comment: Well, it would be nice if we could check the scheme, because with the given information, it seems you're right. But it might depend on if there are more crossings, etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have two candidate explanations.

**One**

[The end of the] [flower] [festival]

translating into

[E (last letter -- i.e., the end -- of THE)] [ASTER] -> [EASTER].

**Two**

The flower in question is not an ASTER but a COTONEASTER whose last letters are EASTER.

Either could have been intended by the setter. The first is perhaps a bit more likely.

(Thanks to ganzogo and Rosie F in comments for pointing out that the first explanation works better than I initially thought it did; I was mis-parsing slightly.)

Comment: As much as I admire your ruthless logic, I'm pretty sure they were going for the first explanation. Especially if you read it as "The end of the", i.e. the last letter of the word "the".

Comment: @ganzogo Actually this one makes more sense. Usually in crosswords "End of the..." is a wordplay. So "The end of the world" is usually "LD" or "RLD" depending on the length. In this case the word is longer than 6 characters so it fits the kind of wordplay.

Comment: The construction you give in your **One** is sound and grammatically correct: "The end of the" means "the last letter of THE", so that yields E.

Comment: @Rosie D'oh, of course you're right.

Comment: @ganzogo And so therefore are you; my apologies for not noticing sooner that you'd pointed out the same thing as Rosie did earlier.

Answer (score 0):

It is because:

> ASTER is a [flower](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aster_(genus)), so your word ends with a flower!

Comment: But the word is 6 letters long, yours is only 5. Unless you're confirming OP's suspicions.

Comment: @Alenanno I gave the explanation for his question. He found the word and asked the flower part only.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that later. :P

Comment: This seems right to me. A festival with "the end of the flower".. yeah.

Comment: I don't think that's sound. "The end of the flower" can't mean "a word whose end is a flower".

Comment: Thank you for this. [The end] + [flower] = [festival]. Also thanks for showing me that I can hide text. Have updated the question for anyone who wants to figure it out themselves.

Comment: @ganzogo This should not be the accepted answer.  It doesn't actually explain the cryptic clue.  Gareth's answer below should be accepted.